Amplify. Storage Getting Crash Android
Getting Crash
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get plugin because configuration previously failed. Check for failures by logging any exceptions thrown by Amplify.configure()."
coding:
Amplify.Storage.list("", options,
{ result ->

    result.items.forEach { item ->
        val otaCheck = item.key.split('.')
        if (otaCheck.size > 1 && otaCheck[1].equals("tgz")) {
            val otaName = item.key.split('_')
            val version = otaName[0].split('-')
            val otaVersion = version[1].toInt()
            if (otaVersion > com.rinnai.central.Common.Common.firmVersion) {
                com.rinnai.central.Common.Common.firmVersion = otaVersion
                com.rinnai.central.Common.Common.firmLastName = version[0]
                com.rinnai.central.Common.Common.firmDownloadKey = item.key
                Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Item: ${item.key}")
            }

        }
    }

After updating
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core-kotlin:2.19.1'
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:2.19.1'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.52.1'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.52.1'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.52.1'

